# Fail to execute url when using DefaultHttpHandler in IIS

Tags: .net, iis, httphandler

I use HttpHandlerFactory to create handlers for handling all types of request(*.*)  , but some static request type i don't wanna handle , so i return DefaultHttpHandler .
but in VS , it works normal , in IIS , just HtmlTemplateHandler and DoTemplateHandler works normally , other request types which in default case all return me "Fail to execute Url" exception .

```
        GenericHandler currentHandler = null;

        switch (extName)
        {
            case ".html":
                currentHandler = new HtmlTemplateHandler();
                break;
            case ".do":
                currentHandler = new DoTemplateHandler();
                break;
            default:
                return new DefaultHttpHandler();
        }



        return currentHandler;
```

following is my web.config

```
  <system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
       <handlers>

        <add name="all" path="*.*" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" />
    </handlers>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue already.

since VS is different to IIS , so , we need use StaticFileHander to handle some static files such as jpg,css,js...

but this handler it's not include in VS . consider use reflaction for create.

```
                    Type type = typeof(HttpApplication).Assembly.GetType("System.Web.StaticFileHandler", true);
                IHttpHandler handler = (IHttpHandler)Activator.CreateInstance(type, true);
                return handler;
```